# Fundamental Group of $S^1\times I$

Tags: general-topology

How do you go about computing the fundamental group of $S^1\times I$.

I know that $\pi_1(S^1\times I)=\pi_1(S^1)\times\pi_1(I)$ and that $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb Z$, so I'm left with computing $\pi_1(I)$?

Also, are there more than one way to do this? I'm asking because this is a follow up question from proving that a loop in $S^1\times I$ has a unique winding number in $\mathbb Z$ but I don't see the link.

Comment: Is $I = [0,1]$? If so, it's contractible.

Comment: Yes, it is. So $\pi_1(I)={0}?$

Comment: That is correct. So $\pi_1(S^1 \times I) \cong \pi_1(S^1)$. Another way to see this is to note that $S^1 \times I$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ (just squish the cylinder $S^1 \times I$ onto one of the boundary $S^1$'s).

Comment: @HenryT.Horton: you can write it as an answer.

Comment: The OP might like to write up his full answer too.

Comment: How about the second part to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to notice that $S^1 \times I$ [deformation retracts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_retract) to $S^1$, so $S^1 \times I$ and $S^1$ has the same homotopy type. In particular, $\pi_1(S^1 \times I) \simeq \pi_1(S^1) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\pi_1(S^1\times I)=\pi_1(S^1)\times\pi_1(I)=\mathbb Z\times 0=\mathbb Z$